# remove php extension that also work within htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite my portfolio URLs within a `htaccess` file. I have this code and it work to some extent.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/|#(.*))$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php
```

However the issue is that I have a blog in a folder and when I try to go to another page from the blog page the URL does not get formatted right.
Ex. `cgarcia.design/blog/about/` and it should be `cgarcia.design/about/`.

Any suggestions on how I can fix the code to properly rewrite my URLs with a trailing slash that also work with sub directories?

Comment: Does `/blog/` also have a .htaccess? If yes then post it in question.

Comment: No, blog doesn't have a htaccess currently.

Answer (score 1):

use the below line of code:

```
RewriteRule blog/(.*)  / [L]
```

Which basically means that whatever the request that comes as blog/any_name_here should be rewritten as `/`